# How do I check if a device is connected to Bluetooth?

Tags: java, bluetooth

*How do I test if my Bluetooth Headset is connected to my phone? I know that the Bluetooth API supports a BluetoothHeadset profile and that it outputs either 2,1,or 0 but I don't know how to use it. Thanks!*
^disregard this

Edit: Can I test if Bluetooth.Headset is two?
Like-

```
if (Bluetooth.Headset = true){
action
}else (blah blah)
```

Would that let me know if my phone is connected to a Bluetooth headset?

Edit again: So the three states are connecting, connected, and disconnected. How can I test for connected?

Answer (score -2):

For iOS and, if Google is correct, Android, you can look in Settings> Bluetooth> Devices. You should see your device there if it’s connected.

```
//to prevent repeated alerts
var h = 1
if (BluetoothHeadset == 2 && h == 1) {
    alert("You have been connected to your Bluetooth headset.");
    h = 0;
} else if (h == 0) {
    alert("You have been disconnected from your Bluetooth headset.");
    h = 1
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to have a program that tells him whether the device is connected. At least I hope he does, as this is a programming q&a site. That would also explain the "Java" tag.

Comment: Im asking about testing that using an app specifically.

Comment: why is the h variable used?

Comment: To avoid constantly alerting you. If it was not there, unless the if statement runs only once, it would tell you if you were connected constantly. If it only runs the if statement when BluetoothHeadset changes, you don’t need h.

Comment: BluetoothHeadset doesn't work if it isn't part of an expression :/